# Proof of connection between improper Riemann Integral and Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

"An improper Riemann integral is Lebesgue integrable if it is absolutely convergent. "

I've seen this statement quite often, but always without proof. I'd think if we have something like:
$$ \int_{0}^\infty |f(x)|dx<\infty$$

there has to be a point $c\in\mathbb{R}$, where the integral doesn't "grow" anymore i.e.

$$ \int_{0}^\infty |f(x)|dx \leq \int_{0}^c |f(x)|dx<\infty$$

otherwise the integral could not be convergent ( similar as to how an infinite sequence has to be a zero sequence in order for the infinite sum to be convergent ).

But I'm having trouble formalising this or in general finding a proper proof. What is a simple way to prove this theorem?

Comment: The inequality you've written down is not correct, it will only hold up to some $\varepsilon > 0$. To prove the statement you can apply for example the monotone convergence theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) to $|f|\chi_{[0,n]}$, where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of a set  $A$

Comment: What do you mean by "an infinite sequence has to be a zero sequence in order for the infinite sum to be convergent"?.

Comment: $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} dx$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ are both convergent and fail your inequality, and don't have any zero sequence.

Comment: Your first sentence is a bit nonsensical. An improper Riemann integral is not a function, so how can it be Lebesgue integrable?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If $|f|$ is Riemann integrable on any bounded interval this coincides with the Lebesgue integral.  We have by the monotone convergence theorem,

$$\int_0^\infty |f(x)| \, dx = \lim_{c \to \infty} \int_0^c |f(x)| \, dx = \lim_{c \to \infty} \int_{[0,c]} |f| = \lim_{c \to \infty} \int_{[0, \infty)} |f| \chi_{[0,c]} = \int_{[0,\infty)}|f|$$

Here I use $\int_a^b g(x) \, dx$ to denote a Riemann integral and $\int_{[a,b]} g$ to denote a Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Or replace $c$ with a positive integer $n$ if you like. The left-most limit still applies if the improper integral converges.

Comment: $\lim_{c \to \infty} \int_{[0, \infty)} |f| \chi_{[0,c]} = \int_{[0,\infty)}|f|$

This is the part where you invoke the theorem of monotone convergence, correct? One condition of the theorem is that $\sup\limits_{c\in \mathbb{N}} \int_{[0, \infty)} |f| \chi_{[0,c]} =  \lim_{c \to \infty} \int_{[0, \infty)} |f| \chi_{[0,c]} < \infty $. We know this to be true, because the improper Riemann integral exists, right?

Comment: @Jonathan: Correct. Riemann and Lebesgue integrals coincide on the bounded intervals and the Riemann integrals are bounded above by the improper integral to which they converge montonically.